Examples of uniserial rings which are non self-injective.
In abstract algebra, a uniserial module M is a module over a ring $R$, whose submodules are totally ordered by inclusion. This means simply that for any two submodules $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ of $M$, either $N_{1} \subseteq N_{2}$ or $N_{2} \subseteq N_{1}$. A ring $R$ is called a right(left) uniserial ring if it is uniserial as a right(left) module over itself.
One of the easiest examples of an uniserial rings is $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ when $p$ is a prime. However  $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ over itself is injective. In other words,
$\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is an uniserial and self-injective ring. But I'm looking for examples(the easier the better) of uniserial but non self-injective rings. Or maybe all uniserial rings are injectives, I don't think so but I'm not sure. Thanks.

A self injective domain has to be a field, so any commuative valuation ring will do as long as it is not a field.
For example:

$F[[x]]$ for a field $F$
$\mathbb Z_p$
$\mathbb Z_{(p)}$


Certainly by now you know that you can use DaRT to answer such questions?

Thanks again @rschwieb! And yes, next time I'll check out first out on DarT. Just a question, for example it is clear that $F[[x]]$ (the ring of power series) for a field $F$ is valuation ring, therefore it's uniserial. However I'm getting to grips with showing the ring is not self-injective using your statement "Self-injective domains are fields". Let me know if my train of thought is right. If $F[[x]]$ for a field $F$ would be a self-injective module, then by the fact $F[[x]]$ it  is a domain it would follow that $F[[x]]$ is a field. Contradiction since not  every $x \in F[[x]]$ is a unit.

@Cos Yes, given the lemma that self-injective domains are fields, you are correctly concluding $F[[x]]$ can't be self-injective. The proof of the lemma is not hard: given a commutative diagram with three copies of $R$, call them $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$, a nonzero element $x$ defines an injective mapping $x: R_1\to R_2$by left multiplication, and the identity map $1: R_1\to R_3$ , and injectivity furnishes a third map $y:R_2\to R_3$ which is necessarily the inverse of left multiplication by $x$.  So if $x$ is nonzero it is invertible.

Awesome!!! But now  I think $F[[x]]$ might not be self-injective :/.  If $F$ is a field then $F[[x]]$ is a local ring, let's say that $M$ is the only maximal ideal of  $F[[x]]$. On the one hand,  local rings are semi-perfect, then $F[[x]]$ is the projective cover of $S = F[[x]] / M$ along with the canonical epimorphism  $\pi:  F[[x]] \to S$.  On the other hand, by the article "When projective covers and injective hulls are isomorphic" by Boyle, we got that in an uniserial ring  ($F[[x]]$) projective covers and injective hulls of finitely generated modules are .......

@rschwieb....are isomorphic.  Therefore, $S$ being simple it's cyclic and finitely generated. So $R=P(S) \cong E(S)$, then it yields that $R$ is self- injective. Maybe the definition of uniserial ring by Boyle it's non-equivalent to the definition I got from Wikipedia.  Now I'm confused :(

But now I think $[[]]$ might not be self-injective  I don't follow. We've already established it absolutely is not self-injective, and that is what you asked for.

Yes it's uniserial and not self-injective.  I just saw that Boyle uses another definition of uniserial rings which caused me some confusion. Apparently the definition of uniserial rings in Wiikipedia and in Boyle's articles is different.  Anyways, thank you as always.

@Cos Yes, Boyle's notion is clearly different in at least two major ways: it does not require the right ideals to be linearly ordered and also it is a subclass of Artinian rings. It is not a standard usage of "uniserial."
